# EF Core Code First Migrations not recognising existing Migrations

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, code-first

A picture paints a thousand words...

I have existing migrations, but when I try to add a new migration I get this error:
"No migration configuration type was found in the assembly..."

I am using Microsoft.NETCore.APP 3.1.0,

Packages installed: Entity Framework 6.4.4, MicroSoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.5, MicroSoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer 5.0.5, MicroSoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 5.0.5

Thanks in anticipation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`.

By the way, you are using `Microsoft.NETCore.APP 3.1.0`and all-time try to install similar to **NuGet package** version and **.net core** version. Your **NuGet package** version is greater than the **.net core** version. consider it.

Comment: Thanks Pritom. Tools are installed already. - I have edited the question.
Your comment about NuGet Package... which versions would you be using?

Comment: if not works. also, change your all NuGet package version to something like 3.1.2/3.2.1.

Comment: Upgraded NuGet to latest version and all is now well.... thanks!